# PDE and Taylor's formula

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, bifurcation

I'm looking to a prove that a function that satisfies the following equations is actually $f(x,t)=x^3 \pm tx$ after changing coordinates.

Here are the equations:

1) $\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3}(0,0) \ne 0$
2) $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial t}(0,0) \ne 0$
3) $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(0,0) = 0$
4) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = 0$
5) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,0) = 0$

I've tried with Taylor's formula, and a few coordinates changes, but I haven't managed to go anywhere further than:

$f(x,t)=x^3+a*xt^2+b*t^3+c*t^2+d*xt$

Where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are smooth functions of $x$ and $t$. With $d(0,0) \ne 0$.

Any ideas? Or a book I could look at?

Thanks for the help

Comment: No one, any ideas?

Comment: Apparently this is supposed to be obvious. It is starting to bother me to not find out why it's true